# "terraform": Unable to run the Module example in Terraform documentation

Tags: terraform

I ran as per the instructions at https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/modules.html. I can see an EC2 instance by the name "consul-0" is created up and running however my cmd window shows the following error :-

```
c:\>terraform apply -var-file secret.tfvars

...
module.consul.aws_instance.server.0: Provisioning with 'remote-exec'...
module.consul.aws_instance.server.0 (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
module.consul.aws_instance.server.0 (remote-exec):   Host: 34.201.64.83
module.consul.aws_instance.server.0 (remote-exec):   User: ubuntu
module.consul.aws_instance.server.0 (remote-exec):   Password: false
module.consul.aws_instance.server.0 (remote-exec):   Private key: true
module.consul.aws_instance.server.0 (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: false
module.consul.aws_instance.server.0 (remote-exec): Connected!
module.consul.aws_instance.server.0: Still creating... (1m0s elapsed)
module.consul.aws_instance.server.0 (remote-exec): /usr/bin/env: bash
module.consul.aws_instance.server.0 (remote-exec): : No such file or directory
Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* module.consul.aws_instance.server[0]: 1 error(s) occurred:

* Script exited with non-zero exit status: 127

Terraform does not automatically rollback in the face of errors.
Instead, your Terraform state file has been partially updated with
any resources that successfully completed. Please address the error
above and apply again to incrementally change your infrastructure.
```

Any idea what can be the issue? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `/usr/bin/env: bash` followed by `No such file or directory`. Looks like it is looking for `bash` to be installed on your Windows box, which isn't going to work.

Comment: It will help if you provide your terraform config